# Rebus pub/sub: async way to reply messages from subscribers?

Tags: c#, publish-subscribe, rebus

I have been trying to adapt Rebus in one of my applications. easy to configure, works well everything. Have to implement PUB/SUB communication to achieve responses from multiple sources.
so what I made is,

- `Saga(Publisher)`

`SearchProductSaga : Saga<ProductSagaData>, IAmInitiatedBy<SearchProduct>, IHandleMessages<SearchStarted>, IHandleMessages<SearchProductResponse>, IHandleMessages<SearchCompleted>`

Input Queue for Saga is - `ProductSaga.Queue`

- `Subscriber 1`
  contains following sequence of execution:

  ```
  public class ProductHanderl_1 : IHandleMessage<SearchProduct>
  {
      public void Handle(FullTextSearchProductRequest message)
      {
          Bus.Reply(SearchStarted);
          //Some business logic to find products
          Bus.Reply(AcutalProductResponse);
          Bus.Reply(SearchCompleted);
      }
  }
  ```
- `Subscriber 2`

contains same sequence of execution but a different business logic:

```
public class ProductHanderl_2 : IHandleMessage<SearchProduct>
{
    public void Handle(FullTextSearchProductRequest message)
    {
        Bus.Reply(SearchStarted);
        //Some business logic to find products
        Bus.Reply(AcutalProductResponse);
        Bus.Reply(SearchCompleted);
    }
}
```

Now, after this implementation, what I was expecting is:
I should be able to calculate number of executing subscribers right now, by receiving `SearchStarted` messages to `SearchProductSaga`;
and once subscribers done with business logic, would send `SearchCompleted` message to indicate saga - we are done. And execute `MarkAsComplete();` on saga.

But result I'm getting is quite disappointed. What I found is, from handler if you are replying multiple times(like execution sequence in my subscriber logic), all messages are sent together to publisher queue, once handler execution scope ends.

Correct if I'm wrong, and suggest any solution if anyone has. I could achieve same with threading. But I don't want to manage it myself, so is there any asynchronous way to push messages to queue as and when replied from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is a consequence of the fact that *a message is handled in a queue transaction in which all outgoing messages are sent as well*.

This means that all sent messages, even though they may have been delivered to whichever queueing system you're using, will not be delivered to anyone until the transaction is committed.

This also means that you'd have to divide your saga actions into multiple discrete steps in order to achieve what you're after.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I could also achieve same, if somehow, I could find out count of subscribers. Is there any way to find that magic number?

Comment: Not readily, no - Rebus' subscription storage abstraction does not present any way of interrogating the underlying storage - it looks like this: https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/IStoreSubscriptions.cs

Comment: there's nothing that prevents you from implementing your own subscription storage, possibly by using one of the existing subscription storages underneath, and augment it with whichever capabilities you're missing

Comment: you may install your own implementation by going `Configure.With(...).Subscriptions(s => s.Use(myOwnImplementation))`

Comment: oh yes. never thought in that direction. Though I have implemented saga persister with CouchDB. Let me check by implementing subscription storage persister with same. BTW: In-memory subscription persister has GetSubscribers() implemented?

Comment: Yes, I found it here [InMemorySubscriptionStorage](https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/blob/907af6dafa4bf878b46c0dd399444c7cf6f32603/src/Rebus/Persistence/InMemory/InMemorySubscriptionStorage.cs) I could use this also. Right?

Comment: Sure, but please note that `InMemorySubscriptionStorage` is mostly for development purposes only - in order to avoid surprises on a running system, you should use some kind of persistent subscription storage for your publishers (e.g. SQL - or the XML one if you just want something lightweight)